# Is there any ways to download or get sourcecode of webapp from firefox marketplace?

Tags: firefox, web-applications, marketplace

Recently I am doing my own platform based on mozilla's Gecko, So I need to run some popular Web Apps on it for testing. In order to adapt to my platform, I must do some changes on these Web App codes. So, Anybody knows How can I get complete source code of these WebApps ?

Note: Usually I download these web apps from firefox marketplace and install on my smartphone based on mozilla's firefox OS. Can I find Web App's source files from my phone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the page of the app on the Marketplace (e.g., https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/loqui)
2. Click on [Homepage] (or [Support Site]), if there is one
3. Search there (in our case, the homepage is https://loqui.im/ which has a link to https://github.com/loqui/im under "Develop" tab).